# Crystal Reports: change order of months based on a year type

Tags: sorting, crystal-reports

I have a report that lists months and some values along with them. If a user selects a year type as "Calendar" then the report lists months like this:

```
Month
-------
January
February
March
April
```

But if a user selects a year type as "Fiscal" then the report needs to list the months like this:

```
Month
------
July
August
September
October
```

I think I need a formula that starts something like:

```
If {?YearType} = "Fiscal" Then....
```

I'm not so sure how to proceed after this. Please help.

Comment: how is your database data?

Comment: My database data is fine. In fact, I can have my list of months to run as I want in my database just fine. It becomes an issue when I try it in my report.

Comment: Can you post dummy data on how months and years are stored in database